# why am i not getting my ubuntu 12.10 login screen back after uninstalling xubuntu 12.10?

Tags: xubuntu, uninstall, lightdm, login-screen, unity-greeter

I installed xubuntu, then uninstalled it completely, but I am not getting my original log-in screen back. It's a simple log-in screen with the computer's icon, user name, password and session details in front of the default 12.10 background in a small log in window in the center. I want the original log in screen. (dotted wallpaper with changing background as you change the user)

Do I have to install Ubuntu again to get the log-in screen back?

Comment: How did you installed/uninstalled Xubuntu?

Comment: synaptic package manager to install,purge command to remove it..

Answer (score 5):

You need to open a terminal and then copy / paste the following:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm unity-greeter
```

and select lightdm as your display manager if prompted.

Also run the following to remove the greeter you don't want:

```
sudo apt-get remove lightdm-gtk-greeter
```

**Updated:**
Now run

```
gksu gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

and make sure the file looks like this:
[image]

Please let me know if this works for you or not.

Comment: led me to : " system running on low graphics mode "...fixed that....still getting the same log in screen...

Comment: and yes...i used synaptic package manager.

Comment: @jd529 I have updated the answer again, could you try editing lightdm.conf as I describe above and let be know if it works?

Comment: thanx  for the answer man but trying to fix it,i tried one too many things i guess,ended up stucked on spalsh screen.by then it was just too much of headache.so i just re-installed it.

Answer (score -2):

Try `sudo apt-get --purge -remove xubuntu-`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Unfortunately that's not going to work, for several reasons. The command has multiple syntax errors. There's no `-remove` flag with just one leading `-`. You can use the `remove` action (by dropping the `-`). However, the way this command is written, it will not remove anything, because `xubuntu-` will not be automatically expanded into anything else. `sudo apt-get --purge remove xubuntu-\*` may do what you're thinking. But there's another problem--**the OP already said they completely uninstalled Xubuntu**. Even with corrections this wouldn't really answer the question.

Comment: Also, most Xubuntu packages *don't* start with `xubuntu-`, and removing the few that do (like `xubuntu-desktop`) will not, by itself, remove the others.

Comment: >Bryce McNab: i already used the 'purge' command to remove xubuntu...

Comment: purge command on what. "xubuntu-desktop"? this is only a meta-package